# Page redirect with condition

Tags: nodes, redirection, 7

I want to redirect the users to a particular page when they view a certain page when there are some conditions. The condition is that the user has uploaded a node, for example an article.

Say there are two pages, Page A and Page B.

Page A Link <-- if the user has not uploaded a node, clicking on this link will take him to Page B

I have installed the node limit module which allows the user to upload only one content.

Comment: can you provide more info? clarify how he/she uploads a content?...

Comment: @xurshid29 I made the edits. The user uploads the content type normally.

Comment: you mean user creates a node? or uploads a file?

Comment: Yes..sorry my drupal terms are not exact

Comment: @xurshid29 I mean creates a node.

Comment: @nabeela ok.. Let me try to guess what you want to acheive, So, I (authenticated user) want to create a content(node. I haven't create them yet). Created it (article type).. want to create another content(also article type), but at this time you redirect me to the `Page B`.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can achieve that using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Comment: I tried using the Rules module. But I'm not exactly sure how to go about it..

Comment: How do I put the condition that user has uploaded one content

Comment: not content.. I mean node*

Comment: Sorry about that @Krishna